# Explain MySQL Join Performance

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have some mySQL tables that reflect the relationship between a BlogPost, an User, and the Interaction between User and BlogPost

I wrote some query to get all the posts that an user have not interacted to. This query is generated from EntityFramework

```
_dbContext.Post.Where(!p.UserPostInteractions.Any(u => u.User.IndexedProperty == "SomeSpecificString")
```

SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM `Post` AS `p`
      WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM `UserPostInteractions` AS `u`
          LEFT JOIN `Users` AS `u.User` ON `u`.`UserId` = `u.User`.`Id`
          WHERE (`u.User`.`IndexedPropertyOnUserTable` = 'SomeSpecificString') AND (`p`.`Id` = `u`.`PostId`)) )
```

This query run for 3.8 Seconds. The explanation table is as follow

```
+---+--------------------+--------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----+-------------------+------+--------------------------+
| 1 | PRIMARY            | p      | index |                                                               | IX_Post_ParentPostId           |   5 |                   | 7261 | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | u.User | ref   | PRIMARY,IX_Users_IndexedProperty                              | IX_Users_IndexedProperty       | 383 | const             |    1 | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | u      | ref   | IX_UserPostInteractions_PostId,IX_UserPostInteractions_UserId | IX_UserPostInteractions_UserId |   5 | db-name.u.User.Id |   17 | Using where              |
+---+--------------------+--------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----+-------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

I tried to modify it to

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM `Post` AS `p`
      WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM `UserPostInteractions` AS `u`
          LEFT JOIN `Users` AS `u.User` ON `u`.`UserId` = `u.User`.`Id`
          WHERE (`u.User`.`Id` = 'usingIdInstead') AND (`p`.`Id` = `u`.`PostId`)) )
```

This query run for 0.6 Seconds

Is there anything not normal about this? what can I do to improve the performance for this query?

Comment: Your aliasing is distinctly abnormal, and your LEFT JOIN renders as an INNER JOIN (as can be demonstrated by executing EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS). Also aren't you missing some correlation between p and the subquery!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way of saying the same thing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM post p
  LEFT
  JOIN (
      SELECT up.postid
      FROM userpostinteractions up
      JOIN users u
      ON up.userid = u.id
      WHERE u.indexedpropertyonusertable = 'SomeSpecificString' 
    ) x
      ON p.id = x.postid
WHERE x.postid IS NULL
```

Comment: This query gives the correct data and return in less than 100ms.
Can you explain why the ones provided in the question is slow? I wonder why EntityFramework choose to generated such horrid Query like the first one

Comment: Quassnoi provides a lengthy explanation of the (seemingly counterintuitive) issues with NOT EXISTS - although it's all a little over my head) https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: This is the link for MySQL https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/